# Bootstrapping Zend Layout and include navigation resource

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation, zend-acl

I have a problem with rendering navigation menu when I use the following bootstrap:

```
public function _initViewHelpers()
{
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView(); // Never inits navigation resource?

    $view->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ')
         ->headTitle('Test');

    $role = ($this->_auth->getStorage()->read() === null) ? 'guest' : $this->_auth->getStorage()->read()->role;
    $view->navigation()->setAcl($this->_acl)->setRole($role); 
}
```

In my `layout.phtml` I have:

```
echo $this->navigation()->menu();
```

And in my `application.ini` I have:

```
resources.navigation.pages.index.label = "Home"
resources.navigation.pages.index.title = "Go Home"
resources.navigation.pages.index.controller = "index"
resources.navigation.pages.index.action = "index"
resources.navigation.pages.index.order = -100
resources.navigation.pages.index.route = "default"
```

Issuing the `$view = $layout->getView();` results in my navigation menu not being rendered. If I comment that part out, it renders fine.

How can I set the title, and acl role in the bootstrap, and still render my menu correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the view resource to your `application.ini` and retrieving your resources directly?

`application.ini`:

```
resources.view[] =
```

Bootstrap:

```
public function _initViewHelpers()
{
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $this->bootstrap('navigation');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    ....
```

Comment: To simply bootstrap view did the trick :) I added `$this->bootstrap('view');` just before `$view = $layout->getView();`